# Open access relational database

Tags: database-recommendation

I have some very basic knowledge in SQL which I mainly learn from some theoretical data science course. I would like to write a few lines of SQL just to experiment and train myself.

Can you please suggest a few free relational database for which I could write a few queries? Those databases can be about health, economy, climate change, social interaction, genetics, .... whatever seems to be of interest to most people.

Comment: Well, you could always look at the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/); see the help link for more info.

Comment: Asking for software recommendations here is off-topic. Try the [*Software Recommendations Stack Exchange*](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). It already has several Questions asking about databases. If none of those fit your needs, post a Question that is very specific about your criteria. And, yes, there are [several good free-of-cost open-source databases](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_relational_database_management_systems) to choose from such as H2, Postgres, etc.

Comment: @BasilBourque Correct me if I am wrong but I am asking for a database recommendation, not a software recommendation. Plus, there is a tag named `database-recommendation`. I would agree that I don't give much specification about what kind of database I am asking though which feels like a potential reason to vote to close.

Comment: I'm not sure about the standards here myself; we’ll see what the community says. Either way, I'm glad to see you participating here. Good luck, have fun.

Comment: From the definition of database-recommendation: "Determining what database product best fits **the requirements and limitations** in a **specific situation**. This is advice that generally requires much more insight into requirements than can easily be gleaned on a Q&A forum such as StackExchange.". You didn't post any specific requirements nor a specific situation, hence the "Vote to Close".

Answer (score 1):

https://www.lynda.com/ has free online classes. Some of which include practice databases and datasets to work with. Or you might try Gale. https://education.gale.com/l-slcl/